# Send email attachment with zend [SOLVED]

Tags: magento-1.9, email, ce-1.9.1.0, forms, zend-framework

I wrote a custom module which is using zend to send the information of a form to a email address.

Now i have a file upload in the form and this file (a image) needs to be send as an attachment of the mail
this is the code of the file upload in the form

```
<label class="label_fi" for="file">Afbeelding:
<input class="input_fi" type="file" name="foto"    value=""    size="30"/></label>
```

I have found a little piece of code which i entered in the index controller but this is not working

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();        

    $mail->setBodyText($bericht);

    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);

    $mail->addTo("Johndoe@example.com", "John Doe");

    $mail->setSubject("Snel offerte");
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
        $newFilePath = "./media/complaintsuploads/" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
            $fname = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $ftempname = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];                   
            $at = new Zend_Mime_Part(file_get_contents($newFilePath));
            $at->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
            $at->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
            $at->filename = $fname;

            $mail->addAttachment($at);
        }
    }
    try {
        $mail->send();
    }
```

all the other text that is entered is in the mail
and is all gathered in this way

```
$name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name');
```

so my question is what did i do wrong and how can i make it so that the file uploaded is send as an attachment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed my code now its working i also made sure you couldnt upload files bigger then 21mb becuause if you do it doesnt work

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();        

    $mail->setBodyText($bericht);

    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);

    $mail->addTo("johndoe@example.com", "John Doe");

    $mail->setSubject("Snel offerte");
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
    if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
        $file_size = $_FILES['foto']['size'];
        if (($file_size > 22020096)){
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($this->__('Bestand mag niet groter zijn dan 21 MB'));  
        }
        else{
            $fname = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
            $ftempname = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];                   
            $at = new Zend_Mime_Part(file_get_contents($tmpFilePath));
            $at->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
            $at->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
            $at->filename = $fname;             
            $mail->addAttachment($at);
        }
    }
    try {
        $mail->send();

    }
```

Comment: Great! You can increase the max upload file size in your php.ini file: `upload_max_filesize = 10M`
`post_max_size = 10M`

Comment: Or in your .htaccess file `php_value upload_max_filesize 10M` and `php_value post_max_size 10M`

Comment: By the way, you might want to remove your e-mail address from the script source posted here.

Comment: eventually i even changed it so that it automaticlly usses one of the magento email adresses

Answer (score 1):

You should put some breakpoints after the if statements. There is no way to check if `$tmpFilePath != ""` and `move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)` return `true`.

I'd recommend either putting breakpoints after the if statements, or doing a `echo` or `var_dump` + `exit`. That way you can check where it goes wrong.

Comment: What i did was this `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($this->__("step1"));` and step 2 after the if's  Result : both not working

Comment: Is the form called using ajax? Try to put `echo 'step1 complete';exit;` after the first if statement, and `echo 'step2 complete';exit` after the second statement. If the form is not being submitted using ajax, that should give you an indication what steps work and where it goes wrong.

Comment: still i t doesnt work

Comment: Apparently `$tmpFilePath` is not set then. Do `echo '<pre>';var_dump($_FILES);exit;` to debug.

Comment: definitly code not workin empty array `array(0) {
}`

Comment: You'll have to make sure the enctype of the form is correctly set: `multipart/form-data`. Also make sure that the method is POST. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp for reference.

Comment: Also the the file will be set in `$_FILES['foto']`

Comment: the start of the form is writen like this `<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customform/Index/send')?>"  enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: You are missing the `method="post" ` part.  Check out the second link of my previous comment

Comment: yeah i thought something like that but all the other inputs are working but i will add that

Comment: okee changed everything now the second if doesnt do anything

Comment: What is the output of var_dump($_FILES) ? Can you post your updated form code, both back-end and front-end?

Comment: I edited the code a few days ago and now it works `$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
  if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
   
    $fname = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
    $ftempname = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];                   
    $at = new Zend_Mime_Part(file_get_contents($tmpFilePath));
    $at->disposition = Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE;
    $at->encoding = Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64;
    $at->filename = $fname;    
    $mail->addAttachment($at);
   
  }`